# How can I send my userID an Token from my client to the Bot through direct line in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: authentication, bots, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have a client that authenticated through log in, I need to pass that userId and token to the bot in every request so that I can use that to hit my server Web api which requires this info. I tried getting the Authorization that comes in the header but it carries the Secret. It would work for me if I could attach id and token to the header.

```
this.botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
    secret: 'yNy9g1Mok1g.cwA.fyks.fghsth.rcKOQUIu558-TI',//params['mysecret'], 
    token: params[this.token],     //I think I should pass it here but this does not work.
  //domain: params['ngroktunneledurl.com/api/messages'],
    webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === "true" // defaults to true,
});
```

Then FROM the bot trying to retrieve the token in the message Controller..

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {

        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
          var keyValuePair = Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Key.Equals("Authorization"));
          token = keyValuePair.Value.First().Substring(7);

           await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog(token));
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Authorization brings the Secret that identifies our bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by sending an activity to the bot which contains the values I need to send. I only had to deserialize the object to get its value from the c# code afterwards.

```
BotChat.App({
        botConnection:
        {
            ...dl,
            postActivity: activity => {
                // Add some custom data
                activity.channelData.MyKey = this.Id;
                activity.channelData.token = this.token;
                return dl.postActivity(activity)
            }
        },
          user: user,
          bot: bot
      }, document.getElementById("BotChatGoesHere"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**ChannelData** will not be stripped by the connector service. Although this property was designed to provide channel specific functionality, it can also be used to pass extra information from the bot client to the bot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-channeldata

Comment: I didn't find a way that the ChanelData could help me send the data to my bot in every user response. That is my main issue, That I need to authenticate the user with every request he makes to the bot. I am using DirectLine.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your value of token or any kind of string to id and concatinate it with identifier so that you can split in the internal code and get it as an array.

use below code:

```
<div id="bot"></div>
<script>
    var spCOntext;
    var FirstName;
    var emailaddress; 
    var Environment;
    try{
        spCOntext = "your context";
        FirstName =  _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName;
        emailaddress = "your email";
        Environment= "application URL";
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
        spCOntext = 'You';
        Environment = 'Local System';

    }

    BotChat.App({

        directLine: { secret: 'Your secret' },
        //directLine: { secret: 'Your secret' },
        user: { id: FirstName ,Name: spCOntext+'*'+Environment},
        bot: { id: 'your bot id' },
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("bot"));

</script>
```

and you can get the value in your bot c# code like this:

```
public async Task AltairQueryResponse(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> response)
    {
        var message = await response;
        var getContext = message.From.Name.Split('*')[0];// get context
        var Environment= message.From.Name.Split('*')[0];// get Environment
        await context.PostAsync(getContext);
        await context.PostAsync(Environment);
    }
```

do let me know if you need any other help